# ZBAR sdk free to use?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

So I have read over this page a couple of times
http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/licensing.html

Maybe its just been a long weekend or Im missing something but the page is almost suggesting that we need to "pay" something to use? Even though it states its open source. Or that Apple might not allow the SDK?

So question is.. do we need to pay for use of this SDK? Will Apple approve an app using this SDK, and does anyone know of any approved apps that are using this sdk?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might get a better answer from emailing the author.

Comment: it states in that page "Most open source projects (including this one) do not have a single author. Tracking down every contributor and getting their approval could be quite a challenge."

Comment: Emailing the main authors would still be a good starting point.

Comment: That is the most bizarre non-license I've ever seen. They basically claim that the license is more restrictive than they want it to be, but they can't change it because they can't contact all the authors, but they can claim to speak for all these authors by saying they promise not to enforce the license. Make you're own call on this one or get a lawyer (who will tell you not to touch this, but that's what he's paid to say).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree, that licensing page is not very straightforward and doesn't do much to alleviate concerns.

Consider using [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) if you are worried about this.  It's licensing questions page is more clear.  I have released an app that uses this library and know that Apple does not (at this time) seem to have an issue with it.

PS: I know this did not answer your question, but what I'm trying to say is: I don't think anyone on SO would venture to provide an authoritative judgement based on that document, so I'd look for alternatives.